# ffmpeg.js to create mp4 from Canavas frames and transcode it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ffmpeg, ffmpeg.js

I am looking to use [ffmpeg](https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js/) or [ffmpeg.wasm](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm) inside a Vue serverless SPA which at the moment uses [GIF.js](https://github.com/jnordberg/gif.js/). The app creates `HTMLCanvasElement` dynamically and adds them as frames to the `GIF` object which is then made available for download and in the case of `ffmpeg` the option to transcode it to another format, say `.gif`. Ideally I want to do the same with `ffmpeg`. My question is more how to integrate `ffmpeg` in my context and how to replace my `gif.addFrame(composedCnv, { delay: delayInput });` with a `await ffmpeg.run( ... );`command?

```js
async createGIFHandler ( layer , addAllTitles , quality , delay , range ) {
    ...
    var tempGIF = new GIF({
        workers: 4,
        quality: quality,
        height: this.mapHeight + this.infoCanvas.height,
        width: this.mapWidth,
        workerScript: 'gif.worker.js'
    });
    let progressCounter = 1;
    for ( let i = range[0] ; i < range[1] ; i++, progressCounter++ ) {
        this.setDateTime( driver , driverDA[i] );
        for ( let j = 0 ; j < visibleLayers.length ; j++ ) {
            if ( visibleLayers[j].get('layerName') !== layer.Name  ) {
                var tempDA = visibleLayers[j].get('layerDateArray');
                for ( let k = 0 ; k < tempDA.length ; k++ ) {
                    if ( driverDA[i].getTime() === tempDA[k].getTime() ) {
                        this.setDateTime( visibleLayers[j] , tempDA[k] );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        await new Promise(resolve => this.map.once('rendercomplete', resolve));
        await this.composeCanvas( tempGIF , driverDA[i] , visibleLayers , delay , widths )
        this.$store.dispatch('Layers/setGIFPercent', Math.round(((progressCounter / gifLength) * 100)))
    }

    tempGIF.on('finished', (blob) => {
        const tempURL = URL.createObjectURL( blob )
        this.$store.dispatch( 'Layers/setGIFURL' , tempURL )
        console.log('GIF Finished');
    });
    tempGIF.render();
},
async composeCanvas( gif , timeStep , visibleLayers , delayInput , widths ) {
    const mapCnv = this.getMapCanvas();
    await this.updateInfoCanvas( timeStep , widths )
    const composedCnv = await this.stitchCanvases( mapCnv , visibleLayers.length );
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        gif.addFrame(composedCnv, { delay: delayInput });
        resolve();
    })
},
```

Comment: You can try running a child process with ffmpeg command like `ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba -s wxh -r fps -i - output.mp4`, and write `ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h).data` to `stdin` pipe of the ffmpeg process, where `ctx` is a `CanvasRenderingContext2D` object. You need to define the framerate `fps` and width `w` and height `h` before starting the ffmpeg process. When done, closing the `stdin` pipe will terminate FFmpeg (after finalizing the output file).

Comment: Thank you for your time but ,how do you "write ... to `stdin`" in the context of a client side ffmpeg instance? Could you please write just the constructor of the ffmpeg and given a ctx how to "write" it to the running ffmpeg proccess, please?

Comment: I'm many years removed from js dev, but a quick search got me [this](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2020/11/23/ffmpeg-webassembly.html)